# Having trouble in saving scalar variable into DB (sqlite3)?

Tags: perl, sqlite

# I am saving output to an array and the array looks like this:-

```
60=20130624-09:45:02.046|21=1|38=565|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|35=D|10=085|40=1|9=205|100=MBTX|49=11342|553=2453|34=388|1=30532|43=Y|55=4323|54=1|56=MBT|11=584|59=0|114=Y|8=FIX.4.4|
```

# Then i converted this array to scalar variable like this:-

$scal=join('' , @arr);

# And now I am trying to save this into db:-

```
my $st = qq(INSERT INTO demo (fix)
      VALUES ($scal));
my $r = $dbh->do($st) or die $DBI::errstr;

#And my table schema is:-

CREATE TABLE demo (fix varchar);

And I keep getting errors :- DBD::SQLite::db do failed: near ":45": syntax error at pdb.pl line 92, <STDIN> line 1.
DBD::SQLite::db do failed: near ":45": syntax error at pdb.pl line 92, <STDIN> line 1.

Any help will be appreicated
```

Comment: Use ticks around `$scal`: `INSERT ... VALUES ('$scal'));` or (far!! better) use parameterized queries (those with the question marks in it).

Comment: it worked.. THANKS!!

Comment: That's awful advice, @PerlDuck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you denote your array is a bit weird. Usually you would write it as

```
my @arr = ( '60=20130624-09:45:02.046',
            '21=1',
            '38=565',
            ... );
```

or whatever your actual content is. But this is not the problem here because you flatten it to the string `$scal` anyway.

One way to insert this string into your DB is to put ticks (`'`) around it:

```
my $st = qq(INSERT INTO demo (fix) VALUES ('$scal'));
my $r = $dbh->do($st) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

**But this is bad** because it's vulnerable to SQL injection (http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png).
Consider the case your string is `foo'); delete from demo; --`. The final result would then be

```
INSERT INTO demo (fix) VALUES ('foo'); delete from demo; --')
```

The second reason why this is bad: Your string could contain ticks (`$scal="foo's bar"`) and that also would mess up the resulting INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO demo (fix) VALUES ('foo's bar');
```

Conclusion: it's always **better to use parameterized queries**:

```
my $st = 'INSERT INTO demo (fix) VALUES (?)';
my $r = $dbh->do($st, undef, $scal) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

The `undef` is for additional SQL options (I've rarely seen anything different from `undef` here). The following parameters are replaced for the `?`s in the statement. The DB driver does all the quoting for you. The more `?` you use, the more parameters you must supply to `do()`:

```
my $st = 'INSERT INTO sample_tbl (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
my $r = $dbh->do($st, undef, 'foo', 42, $scal) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Comment: (Accidental downvote using the app, which doesn't let me undo downvotes)

Comment: @ikegami Never mind, things happen. And thank you for telling.